# Routes problem in Laravel and Page not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have contact form in pop-up but when I click on send button I've got page not found instead of redirect me to the home page.

This is my route

```
Route::post('/contact_us','HomeController@contact_us')->name('contact_us');
```

The function in HomeController.php

```
public function contact_us(Request $request)
{ 
    $validator=Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
    {

      Session::flash('error', "join_us");
      return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator, 'contact');
    }
    $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email'  => $request->email,
        'phone'  => $request->phone,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
        ); 
    $email=$request->email;

     DB::table('application_from')->insert($data); 

    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Application added successfuly');
}
```

And the form opened and close tags are

```
{{Form::open(array('route'=>'contact_us','method'=>'post'))}}

..... form inputs

{{Form::close()}}
```

When I click Submit I've got

```
Not Found

The requested URL /contact_us was not found on this server.
```

Why is trying to load this URL when it should reload the home page?

UPDATE with the form

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {{Form::open(array('route'=>'contact_us','method'=>'post'))}}
         <div class="form-group {{ $errors->contact->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
              @if ($errors->contact->has('name'))
                  <span class="small text-danger ">
                      <b>{{ $errors->contact->first('name') }}</b>
                  </span>
              @endif
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" >
         </div>
         <div class="form-group {{ $errors->contact->has('email') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
              @if ($errors->contact->has('email'))
                  <span class="small text-danger ">
                     <b>{{ $errors->contact->first('email') }}</b>
                  </span>
              @endif
              <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" >
         </div>
         <div class="form-group {{ $errors->contact->has('phone') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
              @if ($errors->contact->has('phone'))
                   <span class="small text-danger ">
                        <b>{{ $errors->contact->first('phone') }}</b>
                   </span>
              @endif
              <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" >
         </div>
         <div class="form-group text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm btn-block">Submit</button>
         </div> 
         {{Form::close()}}
 </div>
```

UPDATE 2: send mail function

```
Mail::send('contact_us_email', $data, function($message) use ($email){
            $message->to($email)->subject('Site')->cc('info@example.com');
            $message->from('info@example.com');
});
```

Comment: Can you please show complete form.

Comment: Have you tried using `Route::post` without `/` ?

Comment: Something like this:
`Route::post('contact_us','HomeController@contact_us')->name('contact_us');`

Comment: Updated with full form

Comment: @GugaNemsitsveridze, I've tried without `/` -> not found

Comment: It's may be silly solution, but what if you try to use simple php redirect? `header("location:/")` ? You can set parameters like `header("location:/" . $_SERVER["something"]`

Comment: Tried like this `$home = 'header("location:/" . $_SERVER["something"]';` and at the end `return $home;` still `The requested URL /contact_us was not found on this server.`

Comment: Okay, I think I found part of the problem. At least with the page not found on server. I've changed the route to `Route::post('/','HomeController@contact_us')->name('contact_us');`. Now the page reload normally but still no email received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your email problem

try to add the following in your **.env** file

```
# For Localhost Email
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

# For Hosting Email
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

these credentials are for gmail-based email, don't forget to do these steps:

1. Go to your Google Account.
2. On the left navigation panel, click Security.
3. On the bottom of the page, in the Less secure app access panel, click Turn on access.

Comment: I think I found part of the problem. Because there is no such page actually `contact_us` and I've changed the route to `Route::post('/','HomeController@contact_us')->name('contact_us');`. Now the page reload normally but still no email received.

Comment: change it to Route::post('/contact_us','HomeController@contact_us')->name('contact_us') if you still want to retain the content of your action attributE in your form

Comment: No that's not a problem what is the url actually. The send email function is

Comment: may I see your code for sending the email? it's not included in the question

Comment: I have edited my answer to suit your question about the email

Answer (score 1):

Please share the complete code of `forms`

i have checked your `function` and `form` and `routes` there is no bugs

I think that the data from the form is staring in the `database` but the `redirecting` after the store is throwing error

> I am not **daam sure but may be**

So Try Changing the

**FROM**

```
 return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Application added successfuly');
```

**TO**

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message','Application added successfuly');
```

And also
**FROM**

```
{{Form::open(array('route'=>'contact_us','method'=>'post'))}}
```

**TO**

```
  {!! Form::open(['route' => ['contact_us']]) !!}
  @method('POST')
```

Comment: Tried both but still not found.

Comment: Also I've tried without storing it to database e.g. commented the line which is storing it - still same.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing the `csrf-token` in the form.
Add the csrf field in the form as below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
```

OR

```
{!! Form::token() !!}
```

Hope, this will resolve your issue.

Comment: hey dude thats not the problem if the `_token` is not  found in the `HttpRequest` it will throw `419` with `Sorry Your session has expired message`

Comment: Thanks but the token isn't the problem and yes, it throws url not found

Comment: @Manojkiran.A yes it throws 419, but recently in a project there was some customization done and it was throwing 404 due to token.

Comment: @Ivanov the issue comes when you submit the form or when it is redirecting after successfull submission?

Comment: @KamalPaliwal, I don't know how you separate those two actions. I mean I'm clicking `Submit` button and I see new page `site.com/contact_us` with not found on server.